# Error Link on Swagger UI

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger-ui

My SwaggerUI works like a charm, but why I'm getting an additional Error section on the page? Not able to find out the exact source of it i.e why it is coming.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your source code. Please post the code.

Comment: i found the issue later and posted the answer. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue with my SwaggerUI. I had implemented an ErrorController to override the way WebApi handles bad request. It was this controller which was appearing in the API documentation. I hided this controller from the the API documentation using IngnoreApi attribute. More details here
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/90